# Better page load performance when loading multiple embedded Youtube videos?

Tags: performance, youtube, embedding

I have a page which displays multiple (usually 10) embedded videos. The videos use the new IFRAME embed code of youtube and apparently for every IFRAME there is a separate request when loading the page. Is there a way to defer loading the videos after the rest of the page is loaded, so they don't slow down page loading that much?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I wrote a javascript thingy (called "LYTE") that will create a "dummy player" (which looks & feels like a normal YouTube embed) for every div with a specific class ("lyte") and id with the YouTube-id. Only when clicking the "dummy" player, the actual YouTube iframe is loaded and it indeed has an important impact of the performance of pages that embed YouTube videos. You can see it in action [on my blog](http://blog.futtta.be/category/tubeken).

LYTE is currently not really available standalone, only as part of [WP-YouTube-Lyte, the WordPress plugin I wrote](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/), but with minimal changes you should be able to extract all relevant code from the plugin.

You basically have to create something like this in your HTML;

```html
<div class="lyte" id="7nuiOe8M6bw" style="width:640px;height:385px;">
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
var nT='newtube-';var bU='http://static.blog.futtta.be/wp-content/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/lyte/';
var d=document;if(d.addEventListener){d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', insert, false)}else{window.onload=insert}
function insert(){if(!d.getElementById('lytescr')){lytescr=d.createElement('script');lytescr.async=true;lytescr.id='lytescr';lytescr.src='http://static.blog.futtta.be/wp-content/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/lyte/lyte-min.js';h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(lytescr, h)}}; 
 --></script></div>
```

This block will load lyte-min.js, which will fill the div with all graphical elements of the dummy player (image, play button, control bar, title) and will add an eventlistener to the div that will trigger the replacement of the div with the real embedded player when clicked.

You can find the plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/) and look at the code [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-youtube-lyte/tags/0.7.3/) (wp-youtube-lyte.php creates the div, lyte/lyte.js is the actual javascript ... thingy).

Comment: Very nice, though with this you have to write your posts with the dummy player in the first place, don't you? So it's not a solution for existing posts if you already have hundreds of posts with embedded youtube videos using iframes.

Comment: Indeed, although I guess it should be possible to apply some javascript-magic to "catch" the YouTube-iframes & replace them a dymmy player?

Comment: I don't know, but it occured to me that I run my own code on my site, so it's not that hard to replace youtube iframes in posts with dummy implementations when the HTML is read from the database.

Comment: Is the http://img.youtube.com/vi/<id>/0.jpg preview image URL an official URL which is described somewhere, or it's just an URL which you found and it happens to work, but it may break anytime if they change something?

Comment: semi-official, in that respect that that is the form the thumbnail-URL comes in when using the Youtube API (and documented as such on http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Understanding_Video_Entries )

Comment: @futtta, I'm using ACF custom fields on my website, is it possible to combine a custom field with your plugin ? thanks

Comment: @futtta, there seems to be an error with loading the video feed data (it appears in the console), but I think that's because things have changed since working on this plugin. Are you likely to update it? The videos still load like they should though

Comment: @Crimbo the API used by above ancient code is not supported by YT any more, so getting title and such is no longer possible.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this solution: [Load the YouTube Video Player On-Demand](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

Basically, it's like replacing your YouTube video iframe player codes with jQuery when clicking some thumbnails.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwkc5hg0/).

**HTML**

```html
<div class="youtube-container">
   <div class="youtube-player" data-id="1y6smkh6c-0"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();
 
function labnolThumb(id) {
    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}
 
function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

**CSS**

```html
<style>
.youtube-container { display: block; margin: 20px auto; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; }
.youtube-player { display: block; width: 100%; /* assuming that the video has a 16:9 ratio */ padding-bottom: 56.25%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; display: block; }
img.youtube-thumb { bottom: 0; display: block; left: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: auto }
div.play-button { height: 72px; width: 72px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -36px; margin-top: -36px; position: absolute; background: url("http://i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat; }
#youtube-iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Automatic, request reducing, solution**

*In WordPress plugin form*

Here is a WordPress plugin you can download and manually install via the WordPress plugin repository. I created this today just to handle this situation. No changes to content are needed, this works automatically once activated on any and all iframes.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lowermedia-iframes-on-demand/